# jQuery to select an element from a list of fetched items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating an image gallery similar to that of Instagram or user photos in Facebook.

I want to be able to allow the user to view each image's details (e.g. date), displayed in a box that appears over the image, when the user hovers over it.

Each image has a unique ID added through php. So, I used the below code to get the specific image id that has been hovered and then show its box (which is display: hidden, by default). This is not working. I guess I am not using the right jQuery selector.

```
$('.itemImgBox').hover(function(){

   var elementId = this.id;

    $("#"+elementId+".detailsBox").show();
});
```

UPDATE:

HTML

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center" id="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="itemImgBox">
            <img src="..link.../<?php echo $item_name ?>" style="height: 200px; width:200px;" /> 
            <br/>

                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 5px; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 10pt;">
                        <?php  echo strtoupper($item_name); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="">
                    <td  style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 3px;" id="<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                        <?php  echo $image_description; ?>
                        <a href="somephp.php?itemId=<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="detailsBox">
                <img src="..imagelink.." title="lala" />
            </a>                             
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <?php  echo $item_info; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>   

            </table>
            <br/>

        </div>
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML, also? It will help if we can reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: why do you need a class as well when you have your id and that should be unique?

Comment: the class is for styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your second selector is not valid due to invalid DOM elements structure. Simply **you cannot have 2 (or more) elements with the same ID** - it is suppose to be unique. The jQuery stops traversing DOM when it finds the first matching element by ID. Try naming them differently, with a prefix for example, or change elements structure to use classes only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This html repeats for each image coming from the DB, so you only have 1 class which is applied to all images. All IDs are unique, so that cannot be the issue

Comment: Look at the 4th line:
`<td style="text-align:center" id="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="itemImgBox">`
and the 14th:
`<td  style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 3px;" id="<?php echo $item_id; ?>">`
it is the same variable, right? Also your jQuery selector looks for element with some ID and with a "detailBox" class, I suppose you should look for its child so your selector should like like:
`$("#"+elementId+" .detailsBox")` (note the space before the dot)

Comment: Just realised what you mean about the IDs. So 2 divs cannot have the same ID for example ?

Comment: Awesome! think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

The first character can't be a number in the elements id.

Do something like this.

```
id="image_<?php echo $item_id; ?>"
```

In your javacript just do `$('#image_'+id).`

Comment: That's true for HTML4, but not for HTML5:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute